# Why on mobile the software buttons overlap a fixed div on my page?

Tags: css, responsive-design

If i can get some help regarding this, it would be amazing. I tried many things but so far I can't get it working as I'd like.

I want to add a WhatsApp button to my page which will be using position fixed to stay on the bottom of the page regardless if the user scrolls or not.

It works great on desktop/laptop screen, but on my Samsung A51 (mobile screen) the software buttons at the bottom of the page overlap the WhatsApp button. This happens on page load only. As soon as I start scrolling, the WhatsApp button move where I expect it to be.

See screenshot
[image: screenshot of mobile screen]

```
  {* WhatsApp button *}
  <div class="ns_whatsapp">
    <a target="_blank" rel="nofollow noindex" href="https://wa.me/message/XNWPJSNFCERKM1">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://azparts.nl/upload/whatsapp-icon.svg" width="26" height="26" alt="WhatsApp Icon">
      Vragen? Online via WhatsApp
    </a>
  </div>
```

```css
 .ns_whatsapp {
     background-color: #03b103;
     padding: 8px 12px;
     margin: 10px;
     position: fixed;
     bottom: 0;
     right: 0;
     z-index: 9999;
     overflow: hidden;
     -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
     transform: translateZ(0);
 }

 .ns_whatsapp a {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
 }

 .ns_whatsapp img {
     margin-right: 0.25rem;
     max-width: 100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have checked out your website on my phone and I found that the width is less than that of the device width may that's causing this problem. Use

```
box-sizing:border-box;
```

in your whatsapp div. Hope this will help you out.

[image]

Look at this div size. The orange color space is showing the padding you have added .This is causing the issue. Remove this padding or add the above code that is box sizing.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question, but it didn't work. I tried adding `box-sizing: border-box` but it didn't solve the issue. I also tried removing the padding but still the whatsapp button is hidden under the software buttons. Only when I scroll down does the button move above the software buttons.